# Comparing signed and unsigned values in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, unsigned, signed

Recently I have encountered a problem with comparing signed and unsigned values in objective-c. Here is an example of this problem:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray array];
NSLog(@"Count = %d", array.count);
NSLog(@"Count - 2 = %d", array.count - 2);
if (array.count - 2 > 0) {
    NSLog(@"A");
} else {
    NSLog(@"B");
}
```

At the first glance it seems that the following code should print `B`. However, when you run it this is what you see:

```
Count = 0
Count - 2 = -2
A
```

Now I know that the problem is with comparing signed and unsigned values (`array.count` is `unsigned long`).

However, this kind of error is very hard to spot (the code compiles, there is no warning and you may not notice that `array.count` is unsigned and that it matters). **The question is how could I avoid such situations? Is there a safe way of comparing signed and unsigned values?**

It is also interesting why `NSLog(@"%d", array.count - 2)` prints `-2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a compiler option, `-Wsign-conversion`, that warns you about potential signedness problems. In Xcode, you can find it under Implicit Signedness Conversion in the Build Settings.

Answer (score 5):

First, it is not safe to compare signed and unsigned numbers, and in your case `array.count - 2` is an unsigned number.

Second, it prints `-2`  because you used `%d` which is the formatter for a signed integer. To print unsigned integer use `%u`.

Answer (score 1):

Here when you

```
NSLog(@"%d", array.count - 2);
```

as it is a format specified, your %d becomes an integer, of signed/unsigned. So it prints -2.

Similarly you can make comparisons.

```
int count = array.count - 2;
if (count > 0) 
{
    NSLog(@"A");
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"B");
}
```

this should print B.